# What is the cause of an IllegalArgumentException at onRestoreInstanceState

Tags: android

There was multiple (more than 10) crashes reported in my Google Play Console with this stack trace (full):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method:0)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method:0)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  at android.view.View.onRestoreInstanceState(View.java:12308)
  at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:12284)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2617)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2623)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2623)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2623)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2623)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2623)
  at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:12262)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1647)
  at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:938)
  at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:910)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1138)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2189)
```

What would trigger this exception? There was no mention of my application's classes in the stack trace. What should I do?

Comment: @NayanSrivastava which activity?

Comment: IllegalArgumentException can happen when a view is not available or when you switch to a new activity while a task is running.

Comment: Show some code.

Answer (score 0):

The following text is written in the Android source code in View.java:12308 as the IllegalArgumentException message:

Wrong state class, expecting View State but received (something else) instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is (view id). Make sure other views do not use the same id.